# Menus don't show properly in latest Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, resolution

I'm using the last version of Mint and I'm having, sometimes, problems with some menus. I can't take a PrintScreen because it happens with the right button function.

If I'm right clicking on a item down the screen, the last options, like "Property" for instance, do not appear so I have to use the keyboard arrows to get to the option. My resolution is 1366 x 768 (16:9).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

On `Advanced Settings` -> `Shell Extensions` -> `Bottom Panel Extension` to `Off`